# Android ShareElement Weird When from GridViewFragment to ViewPager2Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, transition, android-transitions

There are two Fragments, one is GalleryFragment with GridView, the other is ViewPager2Fragment with ViewPager2, User will be navigated to ViewPager2Fragment when GridView's item clicked.

I have added ShareElement by adding the same TransitionName( "gallery_image" + itemPosition) between those two's items.
GalleryFragment's item click:

```
FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
                            .addSharedElement(view, "gallery_image" + position)
                            .build();
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_GalleryFragment_to_ViewPager2Fragment, null, null, extras);
```

GalleryFragment's SharedElement:

```
setExitSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
                        View newSharedElement = (View) galleryView.findViewByTag("gallery_image" + activity.getPosition()).getParent();
                        if (newSharedElement != null) {
                            sharedElements.put(names.get(0), newSharedElement);
                        }
                }
});
```

ViewPager2Fragment:

```
setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
postponeEnterTransition();
setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
                        View currentItemView = viewPager.findViewWithTag("gallery_image" + activity.getPosition());
                        if (currentItemView != null) {
                            sharedElements.put(names.get(0), currentItemView);
                        }
                }
});

...

pageAdapter.setOnLoadedListener(new pageAdapter.OnLoadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(int position) {
                    startPostponedEnterTransition();
                }
            });
            viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
            viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    super.onPageSelected(position);
                    activity.setPosition(position);
                }
            });
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(activity.getPosition(), false);
```

From GalleryFragment to ViewPager2Fragment、back to GalleryFragment without the page change of ViewPager, everything goes well. But the startShareElement disappear when back to GalleryFragment with the page change of ViewPager, the navagation is:

- gridItem1 -> viewPageItem1
- viewPageItem1 -> viewPageItem0
- back to GalleryFragment
- change outShareElement to gridItem0
- gridItem1 disappear

see the [video](https://youtu.be/5j8yw4pktVM)

And, how to show gridItem1 while the outShareElement has been chaned to gridItem0?

Answer (score 0):

I solved. It's ChangeTransform do the trick, ChangeTransform will check the parentView's transform of inShareElement and outShareElement, then create proper anim. So I adjust the parentView of my two itemView to the right size and position.

Remember:
GalleryFragment and ViewPager2Fragment must be setted to the same mSharedElementEnterTransition with setSharedElementEnterTransition();
Otherwise, weird animations will occur.